# Хранение данных в памяти компьютера

Tags: c++, c, память

Есть некий код, который записывает данные в память.

Допустим, ему передали указатель на начало блока памяти, - `void *`, - и числовое значения для записи - `data`. Указатель преобразуется в тип `int`, и записывается разность `data - val`.

```
void write(void *addr, int data = 1024) {
    *((int*) addr) = data - 18;
}
```

Для проверки корректности функционирования программы, копирую каждый байт блока памяти в файл, а после изучаю его.

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    fout << std::hex << ((int) *((char*) addr + i));
```

Особенность в том, что, например, результат выражения `1024 - 18` выглядит в файле так: `ffffffee, 3, 0, 0`, а должно: `ee, 3, 0, 0`.

Почему возникает эта странность? Как байт может хранить такое большое число?

Comment: Где-то байт рассматривается как `int` - но как без кода указать, где именно и что именно происходит?...

Comment: Взгляните, обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы преобразуете байт в `int`:

```
(int) *((char*) addr + i)
```

Соответственно, `cout` выводит *знаковое* значение типа `int`, получая его из `ee`. У вас имеется значение 238, которое - в знаковом представлении байта - отрицательное (знаковый бит равен 1). Вот этот бит знака и распространяется при преобразовании в `int`.

Попробуйте

```
fout << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << (unsigned int)(*((unsigned char*) addr + i));
```

Comment: В данном случае выводятся сами символы, а не их коды, что затрудняет проверку.

Comment: Согласен, подзабыл. См. исправленный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Не нужно приводить к int, приводите к unsigned char

Comment: Разве он не будет выводиться как символ?

Comment: Да, будет. Поэтому потом надо будет ещё приводить к типу unsigned int.